# Is there an easy way to prune disconnected networks in a NetworkX graph?

Tags: python, social-networking, networkx

I'm using Python's NetworkX package to calculate a bunch of network statistics for networks of varying size. I'm sweeping an independent parameter that systematically prunes edges, so sometimes a small network will become disconnected from the main network. Is there an easy way to detect and remove those smaller disconnected networks in NetworkX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorin is correct. The function is called `connected_component_subgraphs` in NetworkX.

Documentation: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs

Here's some code that finds the largest network in a NetworkX graph:

```
cur_graph = # whatever graph you're working with

if not nx.is_connected(cur_graph):
    # get a list of unconnected networks
    sub_graphs = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(cur_graph)

    main_graph = sub_graphs[0]

    # find the largest network in that list
    for sg in sub_graphs:
        if len(sg.nodes()) > len(main_graph.nodes()):
            main_graph = sg

    cur_graph = main_graph
```

Answer (score 4):

As the accepted answer is now deprecated here is a better solution for an **undirected graph** = G:

```
# Generate connected components and select the largest:
largest_component = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)

# Create a subgraph of G consisting only of this component:
G2 = G.subgraph(largest_component)
```

For a **directed graph**, you will need either `strongly_connected_components(G)` or `weakly_connected_components(G)` in the place of `connected_components(G)`.

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/component.html

Answer (score 1):

The generic algorithm is called connected components. You can find a description here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory). It's fairly easy to implement and linear in the number of edges to run.

Not sure about NetworkX.

Comment: I found the function. connected_component_subgraphs in NetworkX. Cheers!

Comment: `nx.connected_components` in modern versions.