# How to remove specific components in a disconnected network

Tags: python, networkx

Let’s suppose we have the below data (a sample of my whole dataset that counts thousands of rows):

```
Node Target 
1      2
1      3
1      5
2      1
2      3
2      6
7      8 
7      12  
9      13
9      15
9      14
```

Clearly, if I plot in a graph this data I have two components that are disconnected.
I am wondering how to isolate or remove one component from my network, e.g., the smallest one.
I would say that first I should identify the components, then isolate/filtering out the component(s) that I am not interested in.

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Node', 'Target')

connected_com=[len(c) for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)]
```

Now I should create a network only with data from the largest component:

```
largest_cc = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)
```

This is easy in case of two components. However, if I would like to select two components and exclude one, how should I do? This is my question.

Comment: This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out, general questions asking for guidance doesn't fit with SO's objectives.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, itprorh66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example data you provided, 3 islands are obtained when plotting the graph with the code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx 

df=pd.read_fwf('data.txt')
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Node', 'Target')
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
```

And the graph looks like that:

[image]

Now if you want to only keep the biggest two islands you can use the `nx.connected_components(G)` function that you mentioned and store the two biggest components. Below is the code to do this:

```
N_subs=2 #Number of biggest islands you want to keep
G_sub=[]
largest_components=[]
for i in range(N_subs):
  largest_components.append(sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)[i])
  G_sub.append(G.subgraph(largest_components[i]))
```

You will then need to create a subgraph of G that is composed of both islands. You can use `nx.compose_all` to do that. And you can then just plot your subgraph

```
G_subgraphs=nx.compose_all(G_sub)
nx.draw(G_subgraphs,with_labels=True)
```

So overall the code looks like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx 
df=pd.read_fwf('data.txt')
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Node', 'Target')

N_subs=2
G_sub=[]
largest_components=[]
for i in range(N_subs):
  largest_components.append(sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)[i])
  G_sub.append(G.subgraph(largest_components[i]))

G_subgraphs=nx.compose_all(G_sub)
nx.draw(G_subgraphs,with_labels=True)
```

And the output of this code gives:

**[image: strong text]**

**Note:** According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012579/is-there-an-easy-way-to-prune-disconnected-networks-in-a-networkx-graph/20012654), `nx.connected_components` is best used for undirected graphs. Since you are dealing with directed graphs, you might want to use `strongly_connected_components(G)` or `weakly_connected_components(G)` instead.

Comment: Hi jylls, thank you so much for your explanation and also for the note (found very useful within this context). Much appreciate it